# PagingDataAdapter item ui is not updating while submitting new data in paging 3

Tags: java

I have an RV inside an alertdialog. Adapter for the RV extends PagingDataAdapter with DiffUtil.ItemCallback.

The problem is, the list is updated and submitted to the adapter with the new data and but the list item view is not updating based on new data provided as shown below. I'm using data/view binding for updating the list item view.

The RV sometimes updates the item view when being scrolled.